# I have a dvd movie that won't play in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, video-player

I'm a novice, but am able to copy and paste commands into the terminal. 
There are some movies I can play, but not this one (a .VOB file)

I've tried installing libdvdcss-dev through the terminal but keep getting the following:

```
mplayer2 is already the newest version (2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1.1).
mplayer2 set to manually installed.
vlc is already the newest version (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4).
vlc-data is already the newest version (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4).
vlc-data set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdvdcss-dev : Depends: libdvdcss2 (= 1.4.0-1~local)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and

```
apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
digitale@digitale-Aspire-5349:~$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-bad-multiverse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

All help is welcome

Kirk

Answer (score 0):

I got to a point in my use of Ubuntu 16.04 when I started having this same problem. Tried to install certain apps and got errors about unmet dependencies and there's never a way to fix those dependencies. After trying everything ( I mean, everything ), eventually, I had to just upgrade to 18.04 and start life afresh. I wish there was another way though I always life to run the latest OS anyway.
You might want to try these:

```
1  Remove ( uninstall ) the dvd player software completely.
2. Update the system
3. Upgrade all software ( distr-upgrade )
4. Reinstall the software
```

As far as I know, VLC has been the only app I've come across that's able to play any type of media extension but if the reinstallation does not fix it ( and you're using root privileges ), try re-install the OS or upgrade it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The second part:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Is about the fact that to run commands like apt-get install you need to be root.  Try running it by putting sudo infront of the command, i.e. sudo apt-get -f install

For your first issue - try and apt-cache search gstreamer to see what packages are available for your repository.

Also try a sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade first to make sure you're up to date - it looks like that package you mentioned hsould exist for xenial.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gstreamer0.10-alsa